# What does "this" refer to in a call statement in a function, as a method of another function

Tags: javascript

If I see a code with constructor functions like this:

```
function F(){}
F.prototype.k = "v";

function F2(){
    F.call(this);
}
```

What does "this" refer to here?  I'm kind of lost.  Would it be F2 or F?

Comment: as shown, this refers to window in non-strict and undefined in "use strict"

Comment: @dandavis - There is no "as shown" because the value of `this` in `F2()` depends entirely upon how `F2` was called and that part of the code is not shown.  See various scenarios on my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00: fair nuff. i should have prefixed "assuming simply F2(),"

Answer (score 3):

`this` in any function is determined by how the function is called and you do not show how `F2()` is called, but what this code is doing is saying that whatever `this` is set to in `F2`, use the same value for `this` when `F()` is executed.

1. If `F2()` is called just like this `F2()`, then `this` will be either the global object (`window` in a browser) or `undefined` (if running in strict mode).
2. If `F2` is called like:

   `var obj = new F2();`

   Then, `this` would be set to the a newly created instance of `F2`.
3. The methods `F2.apply(x)` and `F2.call(x)` can determine what `this` will be set to in a given function based on what you pass as the first argument.
4. If it's a method call as in `obj.method()`, then `this` is set to the `obj`.