# Inner function within another function that is the closure in some object

Tags: javascript, web

"If there's an inner function within another function, the this variable refers to the global object (window normally)" -- cite from http://www.codecademy.com

The question is what is happening in the case ?
I have example:

```
var person = {
   name: 'Juriy',
   speakFunction: function() {
     return function() {
        return 'My name is ' + this.person.name
     }
   }
};
var speakFunction = person.speakFunction();
var words = speakFunction();
words;
```

It's good example and words string is "My name is Juriy". But if I change the person object so

```
    var person = {
   name: 'Ryan',
   speakFunction: function() {

        return 'My name is ' + this.person.name

   }
};
```

My program executes with error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Why?

Comment: The quote is wrong IMO. The value of `this` is determine by how the function is **called**, not how/where it was defined. Have a look at the MDN documentation to learn more about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Thanx, Felix for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example needs to be changed to this:

```
return 'My name is ' + this.name
```

because `this` is already the `person` object in that case.

---

Here's a longer explanation of what's going on in each of your situations:

The value of `this` has nothing to do with how the code is declared and ONLY to do with how a function is called.

If a function is just called as a normal function (no matter whether the function is an inner function or a global function), then `this` will be set to either the global object or undefined (in strict mode).

So, in your example, you have to look to how the function is called because that is what determines the value of `this`.

---

In reality, neither of your examples is a correct usage of `this`.  The first one works ONLY because `this` is set to `window` so `this.person.name` becomes `window.person.name` which is merely a reference to a global variable.  This would not even work in `strict` mode because `this` would be set to `undefined` (which is a good test for whether you're using `this` correctly or not).

In your first example, when you do this:

```
var speakFunction = person.speakFunction();
```

it gets the inner function.

When you then, do this:

```
var words = speakFunction();
```

You are calling that inner function.  But because you're calling that inner function with no object reference, Javascript will set `this` to be either the global object or undefined (in strict mode).  The `global` object in a browser is `window`.

---

In your second example, when you do:

```
var speakFunction = person.speakFunction();
```

it actually executes the speakFunction method.  In that method, `this` will be set to the `person` object because you called it as `person.speakFunction()`.  But, you're trying to access:

```
this.person.name
```

But `this` is `person`, so you're trying to access:

```
person.person.name
```

Since `person` doesn't have a `person` property itself, `person.person` is undefined and you then try to access `undefined.name` which is a Type error.

This would work for your second example (use `this.name` instead of `this.person.name`):

```
var person = {
   name: 'Ryan',
   speakFunction: function() {
        return 'My name is ' + this.name
   }
};

var result = person.speakFunction();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Added additional explanation.

Comment: The main point is the context creates at the moment of constructing function object. Thanks a lot, jfriend00!

Comment: @Juriy- I hope you don't think that `this` is set based on how the function object is declared because that is not the case.  It is how the function is called which is what I tried to explain.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542331/what-does-this-refer-to-in-a-call-statement-in-a-function-as-a-method-of-anot/24542380#24542380) for more info.

Comment: course i'm not :) This is the totally opposite point of your answer. Thnx for href, I'll read it.