# Why does the web not work if I replace keyword "this" with actual object?

Tags: javascript

the function would pop up a dialog that show the number of divs that are display. I have several buttons, each of which when being clicked would make a div display or disappear. All the buttons belong to the same class `toogle`. All divs belong to the same class `codeContainer`. My problem is that I expected that the last keyword `this`, which I marked by a comment, refers to `codeContainer`, so the code should work well if i replace `this` with `.codeContainer`. But the length returned is always incorrect if I do so. Can someone explain this? And What tell javascript that a `this` refers to something?

```
    $(".toggle").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        var divActive=$(this).html()+"Container";
        $("#"+divActive).toggle();
        var showingDivs=$(".codeContainer").filter(function(){
            return($(this).css("display")!="none"); //My problem here
        }).length;
        alert(showingDivs);
    });
```

Comment: Er, no, the marked `this` refers to the *current, individual `.codeContainer`*. Similarly, the other `this` refers to the *current, clicked-on `.toggle`*. `alert(this);` is a helpful hint.

Comment: `$(".codeContainer")` returns a collection of elements. `this` is the current element of that collection. If you replace `this` with `$(".codeContainer")`, you will use the first element of the collection instead of the current one.

Comment: The Web doesn't work??!!! Don't do it, I like the web ;)

Comment: You can bind the `this` you want in the context of the outer function by doing `var that = this` and then using `that` reference from the inner function if `that` is what you want.

Comment: If you want a better understanding of how `this` is set by the Javascript interpreter, you can read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542331/what-does-this-refer-to-in-a-call-statement-in-a-function-as-a-method-of-anot/24542380#24542380